# How to estimate error in a composition of functions?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, error-propagation

Suppose I have functions $f_1,f_2: X \to Y$ such that $|f_1(x) - f_2(x)| < \varepsilon_1$ for all $x \in X$. And suppose similarly that $g_1,g_2: Y \to Z$ with $|g_1(y) - g_2(y)| < \varepsilon_2$ for all $y \in Y$. If $h_1 = g_1 \circ f_1$ and $h_2 = g_2 \circ f_2$, can $\varepsilon_3$ such that $|h_1(x) - h_2(x)| < \varepsilon_3$ be deduced from $\varepsilon_1$ and $\varepsilon_2$?

Put another way, can an upper bound on the error between composite functions $h_1$ and $h_2$ be deduced from the upper bounds on error between the component functions?

Comment: Yes. $|g_1(f_1(x))-g_2(f_2(x))| < \varepsilon_2$

Comment: Only if $f_1(x)=f_2(x)$ though...

Comment: @krm2233 no, then it would just be zero, reread the assumptions on $g_1,g_2$

Comment: I'm confused, the assumptions are that $\|f_1-f_2\|\leq \epsilon_1,\|g_1-g_2\|_{\infty}\leq\epsilon_2$. But if I take $X=Y=Z=\mathbb R_{>0}$, $g_1(x)=g_2(x)=1/x$ and $f_1(x)=x$, $f_{2,r}(x)=x+r$ for some $r \in (0,\epsilon_1)$, then $f_1,f_2=f_{2,r},g_1,g_2$ satisfy the conditions given.  But then if $h_1 = g\circ f_1$ and $h_{2,r} = g\circ f_2$, then $|h_1(x)-h_{2,r}(x)| = \frac{|r|}{|x||x+r|}$  which, if $x=r$, becomes $\frac{1}{2r}$. Thus $\|h_1-h_{2,r}\|_{\infty}\geq \frac{2}{r} \to \infty$ as $r\to 0$ so there can be *no* bound on $\|h_1-h_{2,r}\|_{\infty}$ based on what is given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to assume more about the functions you are dealing with. I am assuming that $g_1$ and $g_2$ take values in $\mathbb R$, but you don't say anything about $Z$, so it might be useful to clarify that.

For example, it follows from what you have given that
$$
\begin{split}
|h_1(x)-h_2(x)| &= |g_1(f_1(x))-g_2(f_2(x))|\\
 &\leq |g_1(f_1(x))-g_2(f_1(x))| + |g_2(f_1(x))-g_2(f_2(x))|\\
&<\epsilon_2 + |g_2(f_1(x))-g_2(f_2(x))|.
\end{split}
$$
Now if I knew $g_2$ was Lipschitz continuous say, *i.e.* that $|g_2(y_1)-g_2(y_2)|\leq K|y_1-y_2|$ (which is true if, say, $Y\subseteq \mathbb R^n$ is a closed bounded subset of $\mathbb R^n$ and $g_2$ is continuously differentiable on some open subset $U$ of $\mathbb R^n$ containing $Y$) then we would obtain
$$
|h_1(x)-h_2(x)|<\epsilon_2 + K|f_1(x)-f_2(x)| <\epsilon_2+K\epsilon_1.
$$

Comment: Extremely useful response. The question is motivated by a thermodynamics problem: I am working on software that computes viscosity as $\mu(T,\rho)$, but thermodynamic state is usually reported as $(T,P)$, so an equation of state (EoS) must first convert $(T,P) \mapsto (T,\rho)$, then a viscosity correlation gives $\mu(T,\rho)$. There is error in the EoS, and there is error in the viscosity correlation. I can isolate the magnitude of each individual error. And what I'm finding is that the total error is indeed approximately the sum of the individual errors.

Comment: So I haven't investigated the properties of the EoS or the viscosity correlation (e.g. are they Lipschitz? I don't know.) But it seems from your response that there is some mathematical basis for the total error to be proportional to the sum of the individual errors? And that more might be learned if I knew more about the properties of the functions themselves?

Comment: I'm pretty ignorant of properties of viscosity correlations etc. but the general result I allude to is that if you have a function $f$ which is continuously differentiable on a closed bounded subset of $\mathbb R^n$, then the continuity of the derivative $f'$ ensures it is bounded, and then, roughly speaking, integrating $f'$ along a path from x to y give $f(x)-f(y)$ (by the fundamental theorem of calculus) while considering the integral itself, you can see that it is bounded by [length of path][bound on f'], Thus the Lipschitz condition holds whenever $f'$ is bounded.

Comment: If you know *a priori* that $y_1$ and $y_2$ are close, then one could also simply use the linear approximation to $g_2$ given by $a(y) = g_2'(y_1)(y-y_1) +  g_2(y_1)$, which would give an estimate of $\epsilon_2+ g_2'(y_1).\epsilon_1$.